# Populate CRM form fields from iframe

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, unified-service-desk

This is about a call center solution using Microsoft Dynamics 365 and Unified Service Desk. On the USD the call center agent needs to see information from multiple Oracle databases (3 databases for 3 products). When a call is received at the call center, the system will fetch data from these databases for the customer based on the number(telephony will be integrated using connector). We are thinking of displaying this information on an iframe in the Unified Service Desk. 
Is it possible to populate CRM fields based on the what is clicked on the iframe?

Scenario: Customer calls to check about product A which he has purchased. The call center agent sees the Product A information in the iframe. When the agent clicks on the row for Product A, the Product(let this be a text field) on the Case form in the USD should be populated with the name - Product A.

Is this possible? Any ideas on how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible: an iFrame embedded within a CRM form can populate values on the form using:

`window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldschemaname").setValue(val);`

For example:

```
productRow.addEventListener('click', function (product) {
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").setValue(product.Name);
});
```

Comment: For Dynamics CRM 2011 this works. However, in CRM 2016 and CRM 365 HTML web resources embedded in CRM forms cannot access their parent form that easy.